# What's going on with Twitter following limit per day?

Tags: twitter, followers

Something strange is happening to different accounts I manage. Some accounts have the regular following limit of 1000 follows per day. But others let me follow up to 3000 follows per day sometimes. I can't find information about Twitter following limit which explains this. I believe Twitter still states it's 1000 per day for any account. Anyone has an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

From [Twitter Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/66885):

> Twitter's technical follow limits:
>
> > 1. **Every account can follow 5,000 users total.** Once you’ve followed 5,000 users, there are limits to the number of additional users you can follow. This number is different for each account and is based on your ratio of followers to following; this ratio is not published. Follow limits cannot be lifted by Twitter and everyone is subject to limits, even high profile and API accounts.
> > 2. **Every Twitter account is technically unable to follow more than 1,000 users per day,** in addition to the account-based limits above. Please note that this is just a technical limit to prevent egregious abuse from spam accounts.
> > 3. **Accounts are also prohibited from aggressively following other users.** Our [Follow Limits and Best Practices Page](https://support.twitter.com/articles/68916) has more information on Twitter’s following rules.

Twitter also says:

> We don’t limit the number of followers you can have. However, **we do monitor how aggressively users follow other users**. We try to make sure that none of our limits restrain reasonable usage, and will not affect most Twitter users.
>
> We monitor all accounts for aggressive following and follow churn (repeatedly following and unfollowing large numbers of other users). You can read more about these below, but if you don’t follow or unfollow hundreds of users in a single day, and you aren’t using automated methods of following users, you should be fine.

Comment: well, that's the point exactly. There it says you can only follow 1,000 followers per day. I have accounts which let me follow up to 3,500 users per day

Comment: That comes under aggressive following, they keep monitoring it, and there is highly chance that they would suspend your account as a spam. _1000 followers per day is just a technical limit to prevent egregious abuse from spam accounts_.

Comment: I dont know why it's working this way, but I'm 100% sure I wont have problems with these accounts. It's been working this way since a long time by now. What I'm trying to figure out it's why some accounts are allowed to do this. BTW, the 1000 per day limit is controlled by code. It triggers an error by API or it just bounces when they dont want you to follow more. But in some accounts this isnt happening at that limit. There is an undocumented upper limit for some accounts, that's what I'm trying to figure out here, and it is very specific, because it is a rounded figure

Comment: [Following rules and best practices](https://support.twitter.com/articles/68916), this is what they have given as of now, for more information how they are controlling it, you have to contact Twitter directly or wait here for someone to come with more information. :)

Comment: I've seen developers of Twitter apps, discussing with developers of Twitter, as which the limits are, and the twitter developers being vague in their answers many times as if they were playing a game. And the twitter app developers being like, hey, we want to make an app that follows the TOU, why dont you just tell us which the limits are?